# User actions after login

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

is it possible to manage actions after user login ? For example after login I wanna check(get some data from DB and check) has user filled special member form. If not, then redirect it to the form page. Maybe some plugin should help ? Is it possible to do it with user type plugin ?

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds exactly like a use for a plugin. - onUserLogin http://docs.joomla.org/Reference:User_Events_for_Plugin_System